# Installing ORACLE APEX on client with different server for database

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

I have an oracle database installed on different server.
Now I want to install ORACLE APEX on my PC but I always fail, since it can't locate the SQLPLUS command.

Is it possible to install it this way or not?

Hope you can help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apex is installed in an Oracle database, which means that you have to have access to it.

You can't install Apex on "your PC", while database is installed on a remote computer (database server).

Therefore: if you don't have access to the database itself (as a privileged user, `SYS`), you'll have to ask your DBA to install Apex for you. After it is done, you'll be able to use it.

Alternatively, if you install e.g. Oracle **Express edition** (XE) on your computer, you'll get Apex along with it. Then you can upgrade it to the latest version (or whichever version you want). Using a **database link** from user in your XE database to your "real" user in the remote database, you'd be able to access data stored over there.

Comment: I see so it's impossible to install it on my own computer if it's database is hosted in server. sigh. 

If it is installed in server where the oracle database is, can the DBA give us the shortcut link for it?

Comment: All you need is URL to Apex and use it in any browser you want (e.g. I use Mozilla Firefox).

Comment: Hi littlefoot, I have installed Oracle Express Edition 18c. Can you tell me what to do to access APEX?

Comment: Is it on MS Windows? If so, go to "Start" menu, find "Oracle" and check whether it offers access to Apex. If not, URL is something like http://localhost:8081/apex

Comment: yes it is on windows. I cannot find Apex and could not access the link with localhost.

Comment: Ah! It seems that Oracle doesn't install Apex along with the database any more :( I apologize, I didn't know that (my XE is still 11g, and it *contains* Apex). Oh well ... it seems that you'll have to install it separately. Download it from the Oracle Technology Network's "Download" section.

Comment: yeah I think so, since apex 20.2 needs ORDS installation. sigh